# Drop query in sqlite

Tags: database, sqlite, drop-table

Possible duplicate

Hello all.

I have confusion in drop query that how actually it work in internally. I heard one of my post that someone says that when we use drop query then internally it'll be used delete query.

So my question is, Is it true that when we use the drop query then internally the delete query also use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it's the opposite - when you do "delete all" query the database will instead "drop" the table and then recreate it because that's faster than deleting all rows.

That's called ["truncate optimization"](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#omit_truncate_optimization).

Comment: You were wrong. suppose I have auto increament with primary key field than it'll be start with 1 not with the last value +1 try it.

Comment: @Pratik: I guess SQLite developers took care of this.

Comment: it's not care if they re-create that means the whole schema will be recreated not only table and it's columns

Comment: yes were right. If they recreate table then how can they manage the schemas?

Comment: @Pratik: They could recreate the schema or anything like that. This would still be faster than deleting each row.